# CA1001 : Implement Idisposable in a ViewModel

Tags: c#, visual-studio, backgroundworker, code-analysis, idisposable

```
  public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {

                if (processFileBackgroundWorker != null)
                {
                    processFileBackgroundWorker.Dispose();
                    processFileBackgroundWorker = null;
                }
            }
        }
```

I am using a background worker in my view model, and I get the CA1001 error in fxcop. I understand that I need to inherit from Idisposable, and implement the above interface. I am more just curious as to how this works and if simply adding in this code arbitrarily in my class will accomplish anything. I tried setting a break point and this code is never called or utilized, and I would appreciate any guidance in how to properly implement it.

Comment: To get rid of fxcop warnings

Comment: Derp. You said that. Never mind.

Comment: So if im understanding correctly, dispose will only get called upon exiting a "using" block

Comment: ...which isn't going to happen with a viewmodel. Right. You *can* call Dispose() explicitly when viewmodels are discarded. Of course, you don't need `IDisposable` for that. But fxcop isn't very bright, I guess.

Comment: right...well thanks for the info, if you want to put some combination of those messages as an answer, i will accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If fxcop pounds its spoon on the tray and demands `IDisposable`, and it's not an option to get rid of fxcop, I guess you're stuck paying your taxes.

It's a bit silly in this particular case, because `IDisposable` is for disposing unmanaged resources when an object goes out of the scope of a `using` block or a `try`/`catch`, and viewmodels don't go out of scope in that way. So in normal viewmodel usage, nothing calls `Dispose()`.

But you do often discard them before program exit (*at* program exit, nobody cares if anything gets disposed -- it's all going straight in the dumpster). I would implement `IDisposable`, make it correctly dispose of the `BackgroundWorker` as you're doing, and if there is a point in your code where an instance of that viewmodel is discarded, I would explicitly call `Dispose()` on it. You don't need `IDisposable` for that, but it's harmless.